# How to set Parent value for Children TreeView Nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

In my program I have a `TreeView` that is implemented through an MVVM structure. I have implemented a `Parent` property in the Data Model of this Tree, but can't figure out how to set the parent of the children.

**TreeViewViewModel:**

```
private TreeModel createNewNode()
{
    return new TreeModel()
    {
        Parent = null,
        Children =
        {
            new BlockingTreeModel() { Parent = ?? }
        };
}
```

**TreeModel:**

```
private ObservableCollection<BlockingTreeModel> _parent;

public ObservableCollection<BlockingTreeModel> Parent
{
    get { return _parent; }
    set
    {
        _parent = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => Parent);
    }
}
```

How do I set the `Parent` property of the child nodes in the TreeViewViewModel?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't use the object initializer syntax for this.

Comment: Are you saying for the Property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) syntax for this.

Change it like so:

```
private TreeModel createNewNode()
{
    var newNode = new TreeModel();

    newNode.Children.Add(new BlockingTreeModel() {Parent = newNode});

    return newNode;
}
```

Also, your object model seems wrong to me. in a Tree-like structure, items may have N children, but only 1 (one) parent. Therefore your `Parent` property should be defined like this:

```
private TreeModel _parent;
public TreeModel Parent
{
    get { return _parent; }
    set
    {
        _parent = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange(() => Parent);
    }
}
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Alternatively, you can override the `ObservableCollection`'s `Add()` method, and have some action to be performed on each added item, like this:

```
public class HierarchicalObservableCollection<TParent, TItems> : ObservableCollection<TItems>
{
    public TParent Parent { get; protected set; }

    public Action<TItems, TParent> ItemParentSetter { get; protected set; }

    public HierarchicalObservableCollection(TParent parent, Action<TItems, TParent> parentSetter)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        ItemParentSetter = parentSetter;
    }

    public new void Add(TItems item)
    {
        if (item != null)
            ItemParentSetter(item, Parent);
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then your `TreeModel` class can be changed to:

```
public class TreeModel
{
    public TreeModel Parent { get; set; }

    public HierarchicalObservableCollection<TreeModel, TreeModel> Children { get; set; }

    public TreeModel()
    {
        Children = new HierarchicalObservableCollection<TreeModel, TreeModel>(this, (i, p) => i.Parent = p);
    }
}
```

which would then allow you to retain the Object / Collection Initializer syntax, because you no longer need to explicitly set the Children's Parent (the HierarchicalCollection is doing it for you):

```
return new TreeModel()
{
    Parent = null,
    Children =
    {
        new BlockingTreeModel() // <- this will call Add() which will set the Parent too.
    };
```

Comment: @EricAfterDark see my alternative solution.